# find max value in array containing positive and negative values

Tags: assembly, x86

i'm reading from the keyboard values both negative and positive, i store them in an array then find the max value, in assembly language

we are using 'INCLUDE Irvine32.inc'. my code works with only positive values when i assign negatives the program ignores all values after that negative number, here is my code for the maximum value:

```
   FindGreatest:

   mov ebx,offset CTEMPS
   mov ecx,nb_temps
   mov ax,[ebx]
   movsx eax,ax

  FindLoop:
  cmp ax,[ebx]
  jge FindCont
  mov ax,[ebx]

  FindCont:
  add ebx,2
  loop FindLoop
  mov edx,offset HiMsg
  call writestring
  call writedec
```

if the array is [6,9,-2,10]
I expect the output of max is to be 10, but the actual output is 9.

Comment: How did you store the values in the array? (e.g. are you certain that you didn't accidentally store them as dwords 4 bytes apart)?

Comment: Also, what is the value of nb_temps?

Comment: Note that you should use `movsx ax, word ptr [ebx]` inside the loop.  Otherwise if the first array element was negative but the max was positive, the upper 16 bits of EAX (input to `writedec`) could be `0xFFFF` when it should be `0x0000`.

Comment: @Michael yes actually the array is DW is that wrong?

Comment: @prl it is the length of the array

Comment: The `DW` directive seems correct since that defines words. For dwords it would've been `DD`. However, you should probably post a minimal, complete, verifiable example instead of just the piece of code that you've currently shown us.

Comment: Dragon, I know it is supposed to be the length of the array, but what is its actual value? The reason we ask for the complete source to the program is so we don’t have to guess or ask about every little detail.